# how to compare two data sets and delete rows if condition match

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter

I have two data sets,  DF1 is a large data set that have 12 channels in  a range of frequency between 20/20K, I want to compare Pinout from DF1 and  DF2, and filter in DF1 to discard those rows in which frequency is not between min and max limit using pandas

*DF1*

```
     Output Signals  Frequency Pinout
0     VOLTAGE_CH012       20.0    012
1     VOLTAGE_CH011       20.0    011
3     VOLTAGE_CH009       20.0    009
4     VOLTAGE_CH008       20.0    008
5     VOLTAGE_CH007       20.0    007
...             ...        ...    ...
2395  VOLTAGE_CH005    20000.0    005
2396  VOLTAGE_CH004    20000.0    004
2397  VOLTAGE_CH003    20000.0    003
2398  VOLTAGE_CH002    20000.0    002
2399  VOLTAGE_CH001    20000.0    001
```

*DF2*

```
        Pinout   Min limit   Max limit 
0         001         250.0        2500.0
1         002         250.0        2500.0
2         003         250.0        2500.0
3         004        2500.0       20000.0
4         005         250.0        2500.0
6         007        2500.0       20000.0
7         008           1.0         120.0
8         009           1.0         120.0
10        011        2500.0       20000.0
11        012        2500.0       20000.0
```

I try to use for loop but in pandas should be a formula to do it more easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge.html)/[`between`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html) :

```
out = (pd.merge(df1, df2, on="Pinout", how="inner")
          .loc[lambda x: x["Frequency"].between(x["Min limit"],
                                                x["Max limit"], inclusive="both")]
     )
```

Output :

```
print(out)

  Output Signals  Frequency  Pinout  Min limit  Max limit
2  VOLTAGE_CH009       20.0       9        1.0      120.0
3  VOLTAGE_CH008       20.0       8        1.0      120.0
6  VOLTAGE_CH004    20000.0       4     2500.0    20000.0
```